# What is the background music of Sir Digby Chicken Caesar but not The Devil's Gallop?

Tags: classical-music, soundtrack

I'm looking for the title and composer of this dark and melancholic background piece that can be heard between `10:06` - `10:23` on [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/1z5BIaFhTX0?t=10m6s). I've looked everywhere, tried lots of programs to recognise it -- without any luck so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the BBC Enquiries Team directly and I got the following answer:

> We did manage to find the track, but unfortunately it is library music and has no information about the composer. The piece of music is simply recorded as "Digby Stately Home Music, Sir Digby Stately Home sketch, Library Music". Other than Devil's Galop, by Charles Williams, the rest of the music used throughout this sketch is library music. In addition to the piece above, there are also two pieces, one titled "By Candlelight", the composer is H Taylor and the publisher is De Wolfe and the other is called "Finger Of Suspicions" by Harry Bluestone / Emil Cadkin, with the publisher Carlin.

Comment: It is amazing that they got back to me within 2 days about a show that was aired 11 years ago.. well done BBC Enquiries Team!